# Table of Outcomes for If/Then?

Tags: tables, conditionals, ifthenelse

I think I need a "table" of possibilities to go with an if/then command, but I'm not sure if one can do that in LaTeX.

I'm generating random equations in the form **y=lx+a** where **l**=slope and **a**=y-intercept and both **l** and **a** are randomly generated integers.

I'd like the equations to appear in fully simplified from. Examples:

1. If a=o and l=2, I'd like **y=lx+a** to appear as **y=2x**.
2. If a=-3 and l=0, I'd like **y=lx+a** to appear as **y=-3**.

More generally, I think that I need this:

[image: First row is l values, first column is a values]

What code can do this without some annoyingly nested set of `\ifthenelse` commands? Also, if anybody wants to update the tags, that would be great; I'm not actually sure which words to use to describe my type of question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Examine the various cases; in this case `\ifnum` is much easier to cope with than `\ifthenelse`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\printeq}[2]{%
  \ensuremath{
    y=
    \ifnum#1=0 % no slope part
      #2
    \else
      \ifnum#1=1
      \else
        \ifnum#1=-1
         -
        \else
          #1
        \fi
      \fi x
      \ifnum#2>0
        +#2
      \else
        \ifnum#2=0
        \else
          #2
        \fi
      \fi
    \fi
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\printeq{-6}{-5}

\printeq{-6}{0}

\printeq{-6}{7}

\printeq{-1}{-5}

\printeq{-1}{0}

\printeq{-1}{7}

\printeq{0}{-5}

\printeq{0}{0}

\printeq{0}{7}

\printeq{1}{-5}

\printeq{1}{0}

\printeq{1}{7}

\printeq{8}{-5}

\printeq{8}{0}

\printeq{8}{7}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\edef\paa{\the\numexpr 1+\pdfuniformdeviate 9}
\edef\naa{\the\numexpr 1+\pdfuniformdeviate 9}
\edef\pll{\the\numexpr 1+\pdfuniformdeviate 9}
\edef\nll{\the\numexpr 1+\pdfuniformdeviate 9}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
        &$l<0$ say $l=\nll$& $l=0$&$l>0$ say $l=\pll$\\\hline
$a<0$ say $a=-\naa$& $y=-\nll x-\naa$ & $y=-\naa$&$y=\pll x-\naa$\\
$a=0$              & $y=-\nll x$      & $y=0$    &$y=\pll x$     \\
$a>0$ say $a=\paa$ & $y=-\nll x+\paa$ & $y=\paa$ &$y=\pll x+\paa$\\
\end{tabular}

or if you just want one of the 9, then 

\ifcase \pdfuniformdeviate 10
 $y=-\nll x-\naa$ \or $y=-\naa$\or$y=\pll x-\naa$\or
$y=-\nll x$      \or $y=0$    \or$y=\pll x$     \or
$y=-\nll x+\paa$ \or $y=\paa$ \or$y=\pll x+\paa$\fi

\end{document}
```